# how can i create dynamic radio group in horizontal

Tags: android

I created a dynamic radio group.
By default it is like this:

```
(o) XX  
(o) XX  
(o) XX
```

How can I achieve the buttons to be the following dynamically:

```
(o) X (o) X (o) X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See developers site:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setOrientation(int)

```
setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
```

Just make sure your RadioButton width is wrap_content.

Similar question (not dynamic): [Manage Layout Inside a Horizontal Oriented Radiogroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551403/manage-layout-inside-a-horizontal-oriented-radiogroup)